# Dynamic job scheduling in django project

Tags: python, django, cron

I want to apply dynamic job scheduling in Django project.
my desired scenario-
admin can introduce activities to their teams member. this activities will flash on company's portal.
so admin can post more than one activities and scheduled them.
so now if admin post 3 activities `A ( for 13-08-2018 at 3pm), B(for 15-08-2018 at 12pm) , c(for 18-08-2018 at 10Am)` so if today is **13th aug** so at 3pm activity A should be flash on portal, in this scenario I need to implement dynamic job scheduling.

Any idea how can I achieve this in Django.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could schedule a crob job for those times, and modify some admin UI to display the activity at the job execution time: https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron

Comment: take a loot at https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html

Answer (score 0):

for these purposes there is [django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/) which can be used as a *task queue* or to invoke *periodic tasks*.

There are many tutorials how to use it e. g. https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/